# PyQt: tab order not working for a simple custom widget

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I have made a custom widget consisting of a spinbox and a checkbox. The widget delegates focus to the spinbox by using setFocusProxy. The checkbox should not get focus.

My problem is that when I use this widget in a layout, the Qt tab order does not work as expected. Below is a minimal working example. In the example, the focus should move from Var 1->Var 3->Var 2->Var 4 when pressing the tab key, but it doesn't.

If I replace the CheckSpinBoxes by regular Qt widgets (e.g. QCheckBoxes), it works as expected. Also using the checkbox as a focus proxy seems to make the tab order work properly. Thus the problem seems to be with using the spinbox as a focus proxy.

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, uic, QtCore
import sys

class CheckSpinBox(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None, label=None):
        super(self.__class__, self).__init__(parent)
        self.degSpinBox = QtGui.QSpinBox()
        self.normalCheckBox = QtGui.QCheckBox(label)
        layout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.degSpinBox)
        layout.addWidget(self.normalCheckBox)
        self.degSpinBox.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.StrongFocus)
        self.normalCheckBox.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.NoFocus)
        self.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.StrongFocus)
        self.setFocusProxy(self.degSpinBox)

class EntryApp(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(self.__class__, self).__init__()
        layout = QtGui.QGridLayout()
        self.sp1 = CheckSpinBox(label='Var 1')
        self.sp2 = CheckSpinBox(label='Var 2')
        self.sp3 = CheckSpinBox(label='Var 3')
        self.sp4 = CheckSpinBox(label='Var 4')        

        layout.addWidget(self.sp1,1,1)
        layout.addWidget(self.sp2,1,2)
        layout.addWidget(self.sp3,2,1)
        layout.addWidget(self.sp4,2,2)

        self.setLayout(layout)

        self.setTabOrder(self.sp1, self.sp3)
        self.setTabOrder(self.sp3, self.sp2)
        self.setTabOrder(self.sp2, self.sp4)

def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    eapp = EntryApp()

    eapp.show()
    app.exec_()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: `If first or second has a focus proxy, setTabOrder() correctly substitutes the proxy.` is said in the [`QWidget`'s documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#setTabOrder). Maybe it has something to do with this.

Comment: @Sevanteri interestingly, when using the checkbox as a focus proxy, it seems to work.

Comment: [It seems](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-10907) that it is a bug.

Comment: Yep, just found that bug report myself. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, this seems to be a rather longstanding Qt bug, where setTabOrder() does not properly handle widgets with a focus proxy. Bug report in https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-10907

Simplest workaround (at least for the case above): explicitly put the focus proxy on the tab order chain, like so:
`self.setTabOrder(self.sp1.focusProxy(), self.sp3.focusProxy())`

Answer (score 0):

Just set the tab property `focusPolicy` to `NoFocus` in the `Designer` application or add the following code to the setup ui method `self.[tab object name].setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.NoFocus)`.